# how to view image on full screen on click of image?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a page in react js. I have displayed content on the left side and images on the right side. I want to show the image on full-screen onclick of the image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please share your code ...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the incomplete questions.

I solved my problem.

on image click I have called below function:

```
openFullscreen  () {
    document.getElementById('image')?.requestFullscreen()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS viewport units: `width: 100vw;` and `height: 100vh;`